# Retrieving JSON data in Svelte

Tags: javascript, json, api, svelte

I'm having a bit of a blank at the moment.

I'm trying to retrieve some JSON data via the Youtube API.

The error I receive is "Cannot read property 'getJSON' of undefined". I've dropped my code below.

```
<script>
  export let videoData = {};
  const { HEADING, HEADING2, SERVICE_LIST } = videoData;

  import  { onMount  } from "svelte";
  var key = 'my api key';
  var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels';
  var channelid = 'my channel id';


  var options = {
    part: 'snippet',
    key: key,
    id: channelid,
    maxresults: 20

  };
  loadvids();
  function loadvids(){
    this.getJSON(url, options, function(data){

        console.log(data);
    });
  }

</script>
```

This is within a .svelte file. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to overwrite the onmount method and make your request async:

```
const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels';
let data = [];


onMount(async function() {
        const response = await fetch(url, options);
        data = await response.json();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks so much :).

Comment: I'm glad to help.